# Segmentation Fault occurs after using global variable in several function

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I'm currently programming my Bachelor Project what consists an RFB-Client and a Shared Memory. The initialisation of the RFB-Client is done, the Shared Memory is created. My teacher told me to decouple the code and I wrote several functions and used a global variable for the shared memory.

But now a segmentation fault occurs while trying to read the content of the global variable. I debugged the code and found out: The content of the global variabel "my_shm" is always "0x00" :-/
Could you please help me?

These are the portions of code where the problem occurs:
(I know, this is a long code, but sending just parts of it would be useless...)

```
char *my_shm; --> //global variable

int SHM_init (int shmid, char* shm, key_t key, long int size) {


    /* Create a new (System V) shared memory segment of the specified size */
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT|0777);
    /* Check if SHM creation was successful */
    if (shmid < 0) {
        /* DBG: Debug message to show which point of the program has been passed */
        DBG_PRINT("C\n");

        /* Check if creation failed because of already existing SHM */
        if (EEXIST == errno) {
            /* DBG: Debug message to show which point of the program has been passed */
            DBG_PRINT("CC\n");
            /* Delete already existing SHM with shmctl */
            shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        } else {
            /* DBG: Debug message to show which point of the program has been passed */
            DBG_PRINT("CCC\n");
        }

        /* Creation and initialization of SHM failed */
        return -1;
    }
    /* Attach the SHM data pointer to the previously created SHM segment */
    shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    if(shm == (char *) -1) {
        /* Attaching failed */
        return -1;
    }
    DBG_PRINT("Shared Memory Initialization successful\n");
    /* Creation and initialization of shared memory was successful */
    return 0;
}

void RFB_update(rfbClient* client) {    

    DBG_PRINT("RFB_update called\n");
    int i,j;

    rfbPixelFormat* pformat=&client->format;

    DBG_PRINT("A\n");

    /*bytesPerPix: variable which stores Bytes per Pixel*/
    int bytesPerPix = pformat->bitsPerPixel/8;

    DBG_PRINT("B\n");

    /*row= width of frame*bytes per Pixel*/
    int row=client->width*bytesPerPix;

        DBG_PRINT("C\n");

    char byte_to_write;

    //as long as j is smaller than 128*(width*bytesPerPix)
    for(j=0;j<client->height*row;j+=row) {
        //as long as i is smaller than 128 * bytesPerPix
        for(i=0;i<client->width*bytesPerPix;i+=bytesPerPix) {      
            /*frameBuff: Pointer on FrameBuffer*/        
         unsigned char* frameBuff = client->frameBuffer+j+i;  
            unsigned int v;         

           if(bytesPerPix==4)
                v=(unsigned int*)frameBuff;

            byte_to_write = ((v>>pformat->redShift)*256/(pformat->redMax+1));
            SHM_write_byte(my_shm,byte_to_write);

            byte_to_write = ((v>>pformat->greenShift)*256/(pformat->greenMax+1));
            SHM_write_byte(my_shm,byte_to_write);

            byte_to_write = ((v>>pformat->blueShift)*256/(pformat->blueMax+1));
            SHM_write_byte(my_shm,byte_to_write);


        }
    }

    DBG_PRINT("RFB_update successful, Shared Memory is filled\n");  
}

int SHM_write_byte (char** shm, char byte) {


    /*Check if pointer to SHM is valid */
    if (shm == (char **) -1) {
        /* Pointer is invalid */
        return -1;
    }
    shm = byte;
    shm++;

    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (SHM_init(shmid, my_shm, SHM_KEY, SHM_SIZE) != 0) {
        DBG_PRINT("Shared Memory initialized\n");
        /* Couldn't initialize SHM,initializing failed */
        return -1;
    }
    /* Initialize RFB Client         */
    if (RFB_client_init(rfb_client, (FinishedFrameBufferUpdateProc)RFB_update) != 0) {
        DBG_PRINT("Couldn't initialize client\n");
        /* Couldn't initialize Client,initializing failed */
        return -1;

}
```

--> everywhere the variable "my_shm" is used: the content is: 0x00...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a very common problem here on stackoverflow.com today, and the problem is that you pass arguments to function *by value* and not *by reference*.

What that means is that when you pass an argument to a function, its value is copied, and the function only work on the copy locally inside the function. As you should know, modifying a copy will of course not modify the original.

C does not have pass by reference, but it can be emulated by using pointers. In your case, since you have a pointer you need to pass a pointer to the pointer using the address-of operator, like

```
SHM_init(shmid, &my_shm, SHM_KEY, SHM_SIZE)
//              ^
//              |
// Note ampersand (address-of operator) here
```

You of course need to modify the function to actually accept a pointer to the pointer:

```
int SHM_init (int shmid, char** shm, key_t key, long int size)
```

And of course use the dereference operator `*` when using the variable:

```
*shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```